# Android Studio waiting for build to finish

Tags: android, android-studio, android-menu

I have a problem. When I start a new project in Android Studio and select a navigation drawer activity it happens. I don't have access to my `activiy_main_drawer.xml` on "Design" and it keeps saying "Waiting for build to finish.". I really don't know what I have to do. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've just run into the exact same problem. I simply solved it by choosing `Sync Project with Gradle Files`. This will trigger a Gradle re-import and a build.

As of Android Studio v3.2, the icon is located near the top right tool bar. You can also find it using `Find Action` shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: It worked... But after that i had to do Invalidate cache and restart too...

Comment: Thanks, in Android Studio 3.3.2 solved in the same way.

Comment: Restarting and and invalidating cache didn't work for me. Surprisingly this worked for me. My only regret is only having 1 upvote.

Comment: It worked, only Sync Project with Gradle Files and layout xml finisih to build

Answer (score 12):

You can do the following:

**"File > Sync Project with Gradle files"** (worked for me)

**File > Invalidate Cache & Restart > Just Restart**

**OR**

**File > Invalidate Cache & Restart > Invalidate & Restart**

**Close Project** and **Re-Import the Project**

Answer (score 8):

File -> Sync project with Gradle files

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was, from the top menu:

```
Build -> Clean
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

After that the xml design worked

Answer (score 2):

Syncing gradle, reopening, rebuilding, invalidating caches and restarting, trying different **Android studio** versions. None of these helped. When I would open XML preview I would still see that damn issue.

What helped in the end is closing **Android studio**, going to gradle directory:

```
cd ~/.gradle/
```

And deleting caches folder:

```
rm -rf caches
```

After that reopening **Android studio** will take some time as it still has some rebuilding to do, but afterwards all xml layouts were being properly rendered again.

Comment: It has helped. I have had only to restart Android Studio again once it has rebuild the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 (#AI-173.4819257), Android Build Plugin for Gradle 3.1.3 and Gradle 4.4. I tried all possible options mentioned on various posts but nothing worked for me. I want to use ConstraintLayout which is default with AS 3.1.3. My observation and workaround are as follows.

**Observation:** This issue occurs when a new project created with empty activity and default layout.  I also get "IDE Error Occurred" once Gradle sync finishes.

**Workaround:** Create an empty activity, activity class (`MainActivity.java`) and layout (`activity_main.xml`). Once it is done, create a new layout file (say `activity_cltest.xml`) using New -> Android Resource File after clicking right button on "app". Create new layout as per your requirements. Once done, update `MainActivity.java` by replacing `R.layout.activity_main` with `R.layout.activity_cltest`.

I also tried to copy content of `activity_cltest.xml` to `activity_main.xml` but still for `activity_main.xml`, error persists. Effectively, once a new project is created, `activity_main.xml` should not be used and deleted.

However, for some reasons, syntax highlighting of "R.layout.activity_cltest" within `MainActivity.java` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new XML file using the same name and copy paste activiy_main_drawer.xml file codes. It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have the save problem, the Android SDK was missing from my system.
After installation of this missing SDK, its running fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I specified recycler view's tools:listItem="<item_layout>" in body of <item_layout> (nested recyclerviews). Just removing this tools option solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my 3.1.2 and installed version 3.2 Canary 18 from [Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). Everything is fine now.

We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I resolved it with the help on this page and a little bit more effort.

I installed Android Studio v.3.3.1 today on my Zenbook. I was stuck with the same error "waiting for a build to finish" and Display tab was not showing up for activity_main.xml
Here is what I did to resolve this error.

**Step 1.** I searched for SDK tools and downloaded required SDK versions.

**Step 2.** downloaded Gradle 5.2.1 and extracted the files in Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle

**Step 3.** File>Settings>Build..>Gradle and choose the local distribution of Gradle 5.2.1

**Step 4.** Go to File>Sync Project with Gradle files and allow some time to sync...

finish() :) developing android with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

My experience: I was accidentally importing "myself" into the view, creating infinite loop:

`item_task.xml`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    tools:itemCount="3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_task" />   <---- circular dependency mistake
```

Setting a correct list item in the recycler view solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to AS 3.6 RC1 because of this time-waster but it still intermittently occurs!

Simply restarting AS has *so far* been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this problem. The above solution wasn't worked for me. 
I just `restarted` my `Android Studio` by closing the Android Studio application and opening it again from Start Menu. It works for me. Try this solution if the above not working. Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using an alpha version of material design lib, and it was not able  to render any view in the project. Solved by downgrading to a stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck w/ the issue for a month, got it after AndroidX update.
Tried to invalidate caches, manually remove them (project, grade, studio), re-install studio, re-import project - nothing helped.

This script resolved it finally (w/ -nuke option)

https://github.com/rock3r/deep-clean

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while converting the code from java to kotlin some library may get imported like **import android.R**
Just remove this library.

Check this **tools:context=".MainActivity"** in xml while copying another XML the class name will also get copy.

Else try File -> Sync project with gradle or rebuild the project.