# Android UI Designer (IntelliJ) - Waiting for build to finish?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, plugins, multi-module

I have a maven multi module project. Recently I added an android module. I can build and deploy the apk with maven and it works great. But I can't seem to get the Android UI Designer to load. All I get to see is an endless loading screen.

[image]

But what is IntelliJ trying to build? All I did was adding an Android Facette to the module, so I can edit the resource xmls.

I know that you should use Gradle for building android projects. But this project was build on maven and the android module must be too build with maven. IntelliJ also wants me to configure the Android Framework that was detected. But then it tells me that no Frameworks where detected.
Has anybody experinced something like this?

Edit:
Here are the log files:

```
2018-08-30 17:55:51,567 [  57685]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent   - project roots have changed 
2018-08-30 17:55:51,686 [  57804]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-08-30 17:55:51,782 [  57900]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 96ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-08-30 17:55:52,583 [  58701]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput 
2018-08-30 17:55:52,583 [  58701]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens
```

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: The log doesn't show anything special to me. Just the startup log and some info logging.

Comment: This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528597/2351

Comment: I think Maven is not the issue. I use Gradle for my multi-project build and I have the same issue.