# My Android Studio layout preview is stuck on "Wating for build to finish"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio on Kali Linux but the layout preview is [getting stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF8Q0.png) on

> Wating for build to finish...

I have tried all the possible ways to solve like reinstalling Android Studio, invalidate cache but nothing works for me. I am using OpenJDK that is already install on Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio waiting for build to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737865/android-studio-waiting-for-build-to-finish)